# c++ - Function pointer object seems not to to exist

Tags: c++, function-pointers, undefined-symbol

I'm writing some kind of libary which organizes and keeps track of some tasks. Whenever a nwe task is called my libary uses a function pointer given in the constructor. But when I try to call it I get the error `Symbol not found`

In the Header file I declared it as:

```
template <class T>
class TaskManager
{
private:
    // other variables
    T TaskID;  // This is defined like this (just to clear things up)
    void (*TaskHandler)(T, TaskManager<T>*);
    // some more stuff
};
```

I call it like

```
template <class T>
void TaskManager<T>::startActualTask()
{
    (*TaskManager<T>::TaskHander)(TaskID, this);    // Errors!
}
```

or

```
template <class T>
void TaskManager<T>::startActualTask()
{
    TaskManager<T>::TaskHander(TaskID, this);       // Errors!
}
```

(Removing `TaskManager<T>::` in front of ´TaskHander(TaskID, this);´ did not help.)

But it cannot find the symbol `TaskHandler`. No matter what i tried so far!

The full error is:

```
e:\eigene dateien\visual studio 2010\projects\brainstonemod - publish\brainstonemod - publish\TaskManager.cpp(212): error C2039: 'TaskHander': Is no element of 'TaskManager<T>'
          with
          [
              T=int
          ]
          e:\eigene dateien\visual studio 2010\projects\brainstonemod - publish\brainstonemod - publish\TaskManager.cpp(211): At the compiling of the class template of the void TaskManager<T>::startActualTask(void) member function
          with
          [
              T=int
          ]
          e:\eigene dateien\visual studio 2010\projects\brainstonemod - publish\brainstonemod - publish\TaskManager.cpp(73): At the compiling of the class template of the void TaskManager<T>::addTask(Task<T>) member function
          with
          [
              T=int
          ]
          e:\eigene dateien\visual studio 2010\projects\brainstonemod - publish\brainstonemod - publish\TaskManager.cpp(9): At the compiling of the class template of the TaskManager<T>::TaskManager(std::wstring,std::wstring,void (__cdecl *)(T,TaskManager<T> *)) member function
          with
          [
              T=int
          ]
          main.cpp(14): See the Instatiation of the just compiled class template "TaskManager<T>".
          with
          [
              T=int
          ]
```

(I had to translate this. So it might not be acurate translated!)

This might also be interesting:

```
template <class T>
TaskManager<T>::TaskManager(wstring title, wstring subtitle, void (*taskHandler)(T, TaskManager<T>*)) :
    // Some intatiations
{
    TaskHandler = taskHandler;
    // More contructor stuff
}
```

How could i solve this?

Comment: Perhaps it's because you declared it as a non-static private variable?

Comment: I'm calling it in an nonstatic member function. Calling it should not be a problem. The error is, as mentioned above, the compiler cannot find the symbol `TaskHandler`

Comment: Where are you calling it from? Within the TaskManager class?

Comment: Can we get the line of code that triggers the error? Because that code compiles for me.

Comment: Can we get the exact error message, because it might contain some additional information which is useful?  (The code you post should compile.)

Comment: ok. Just give me a little bit. I need to translate it since my compiler is set to output everything in German. The translation might not be 100% correct.

Comment: I dont know if it is care, but your are calling `TaskHander` and not `TaskHandler` is it a typo error?

Comment: That was the error! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a typo. I spelled it `TaskHander` but it's `TaskHandler` (I forgot the `l`)

Thank you anyways!

Answer (score 0):

If it's an ordinary member that is a function pointer (which is what it seems to be in your class declaration), you should call it like:

```
template <class T>
void TaskManager<T>::startActualTask()
{
    TaskHandler(TaskID, this);
}
```

You only use the `TaskManager<T>::` prefix for **static** members or typedefs.

Comment: Both should work.  And the question says it didn't work either way.